# npm | ERR! code EEXIST | Refusing to delete | File exists | Move it away, and try again

Tags: javascript, angular, maven, npm, jhipster

When executing npm, I get the next error message:

```
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] npm ERR! path C:\Desarrollo\DragoMED.web\node_modules\.bin\webpack-dev-server.cmd
[ERROR] npm ERR! code EEXIST
[ERROR] npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Desarrollo\DragoMED.web\node_modules\.bin\webpack-dev-server.cmd: is outside C:\Desarrollo\DragoMED.web\node_modules\webpack-dev-server and not a link[ERROR] npm ERR! File exists: C:\Desarrollo\DragoMED.web\node_modules\.bin\webpack-dev-server.cmd
[ERROR] npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[ERROR] npm ERR!     C:\Users\spoveda2\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-18T16_17_00_119Z-debug.log
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10:54 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-11-18T16:17:00Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:npm (npm install) on project bdm: Failed to run task: 'npm install' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I don't know what to do... I have run npm i after removing node_modules and package-lock.json, but it didn't work for me neither...

Answer (score 0):

try to see the folder Roaming under the AppData folder (you can directly type : **%AppData%**)

[image]

- then delete the **npm-cache** folder
- after that delete the    node-modules and run npm i